# Como saber las clases que utiliza mi proyecto Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera se ver cuales son las clases que se utilizan en mi proyecto java, pues uso algunas librerias de clases extensas y quiera ver cual de sus clases son las que verdaderamente utilizo, para eliminar las demás y que el proyecto se sea tan grande.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: para que sistema de construcción? [tag:maven], [tag:ant], [tag:gradle], [tag:bazel], etc?

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando Eclipse, pulsas CONTROL+MAYUS+O y todos los imports se reorganizan.

Por ejemplo, si tienes el siguiente import:

```
import java.util.*;
```

Estás importando todas las clases de java.util, y a lo mejor sólo estás haciendo uso un dos o tres. Al pulsar CONTROL+MAYUS+O en Eclipse, se reorganizará, eliminará las que no está usando, y cambiará los asteríscos por las clases que realmente necesitas.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

No sé si es exactamente la respuesta que buscabas, pero si lo es y estás usando otro IDE a lo mejor es otra combinación de teclas.

Comment: No es exactamente lo que buscaba pero me sirve para otras cosas gracias, en realidad lo que quiero es saber las clases q utiliza la aplicacion, es decir tengo una clase validarFecha que tiene 5 import, pero esa clase no es usada por la aplicacion, es decir que se puede eliminar y no pasa nada, no se si me explico, quiero saber las clases de las que depende la aplicacion, porque uso varias librerias de utiles genericas que he creado conel tiempo y hay clases que no me hacen falta, pero como es tanto código no es fácil revizar una por una a ver cual es la que no se usa.